# Tumblr arrow keys navigation using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, navigation, tumblr

How do you create arrow keys navigation for a Tumblr theme using JavaScript?

I'm trying to write some JavaScript to allow users of a Tumblr theme to use the `left` and `right` arrow keys to navigate pages.

I've managed to get the basic concept working:

```
document.onkeydown = function(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    var key = event.keyCode;
    var currentPage = {CurrentPage};
    // left arrow key
    if (key == 37) {
        var previousPage = currentPage - 1;
        window.location.href = "/page/" + previousPage;
    }
    // right arrow key
    if (key == 39) {
        var nextPage = currentPage + 1;
        window.location.href = "/page/" + nextPage;
    }
};
```

This runs into the problem of users being able to go beyond the last page and might (I'm not exactly sure) work on permalink pages. However, it would be much easier to use the `{PreviousPage}` and `{NextPage}` variables for the URLs, but I can't get them to work in JavaScript for some reason. Even if I prefix them with JS (i.e. `{JSPreviousPage}` and `{JSNextPage}`) they still resolve to nothing, despite the variables working fine in HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add next and prev IDs to your pagination anchors links. Then try this:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
var url = false;
    // Left arrow key code
    if (e.which == 37) {  
        url = $('#prev').attr('href');
    }
    // Right arrow key code
    else if (e.which == 39) {  
        url = $('#next').attr('href');
    }

    if (url) {
        window.location = url;
  }
```

});

Comment: Thanks. Completely over thought it.